# Как сопоставить поля двух таблиц?

Tags: mysqli

Есть 2 таблицы products & users. Юзеры голосуют за продукты. Как сопоставить голоса (golos) каждого продукта с product_id другой таблицы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from users u
join products p on p.id = u.product_id
```